# How to define a group structure on a given arbitrary set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am doing a course in Abstract Algebra, and my teacher gave me a question: 
**"Find all possible group structures on a set X whose cardinality is ≤ 4."**

I know basic group theory, but I am unable to understand what exactly does the question expect us to do (meaning of the question in simple language, and a possible technique or way to answer such questions, exact answer not needed.)

Comment: Roughly speaking, it's "find all groups of order $\le4$ up to isomorphism".

Comment: Okay. That sounds familiar. Thanks. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups

Comment: I think the question could (should?) be interpreted slightly more generally than @LordShark's comment implies. In particular, fixing a set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ one could define a group structure where $a$ is the identity (and the other elements do other stuff). Alternatively, $b$ might be the identity. These two structures are different, but of course may be isomorphic.

Comment: I think it is perfectly possible to interpret this question either way. Either find all group structures on a set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ (with named elements),  or find all group structures on aset of four elements which you can name yourself i.e. let's call the identity $a$, etc.

Comment: I have not miscounted, then there are $16$ such structures, $12$ for the cyclic group and $4$ for the Klein 4-group.

Comment: I agree with user1729's comment. The question has a clear literal meaning. Finding isomorphism classes is a natural first step and skipping the second step is cheating (or the question should have been asked differently). In general each isomorphism class, with automorphism group of order $k$, occurs $n!/k$ times. For $n=4$, the cyclic group $C_4$ thus occurs $24/2=12$ times, and Klein occurs $24/6=4$ times as computed by Derek.

Comment: For group tables with $4$ elements see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300393/group-tables-for-a-group-of-four-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde For reasons discussed in the comments, I do not believe that that answers the question.

Comment: This is not so clear for me. I tend to think that the question was intended that way. If not, then the OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are specifically wanting

1. to understand what the question asks, and
2. a hints.

I will address these and (in view of (2)) not give a worked solution.

1) As I read it, the question essentially wants you to fix a set with $4$ elements and find all group structures on this set. A different (easier) question is "find all groups with four elements" (but then the question should have read "Find all possible group structures *up to isomorphism* on a set $X$ whose cardinality is $\leq 4$).

Possibly this second interpretation is what was *intended* when the question was written, but I do not think this is what the question is actually asking. [This is discussed in the comments to the question.]

2) It is well-known that there are two groups of order $4$, up to isomorphism. If you are unaware of this fact then you should start by verifying it. Lets fix the set $X=\{a, b, c, d\}$. Every bijection from the set $X$ to the group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ defines a group structure on $X$. So, for example, $a\mapsto 0$, $b\mapsto 1$, $c\mapsto 2$, $d\mapsto 3$ gives a group structure, while $a\mapsto 1$, $b\mapsto 2$, $c\mapsto 3$, $d\mapsto 0$ gives a different group structure. There are $4!$ bijections between $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$, and similarly $4!$ between $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the Klein $4$-group). Hence, there are at most $4!+4!$ group structures which we can put on $X$. However, there is some double-counting going on. The actual number of group structures is $4!/2+4!/6=16$. Why?